# Show a different child in a Row depending on if it fits or not

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

Is there some widget that makes it easy to swap out one child in a `Row` for another smaller one in case the width is not enough to fit the bigger one?

In the image below, the Widget `B` is a full width version, and `D` is a mini version of the same widget.

[image]

Note that I do not want the widget to adjust its size seamlessly like a `Flexible` or `Expanded` - I want it to be either as wide as `B`, or if that doesn't fit I want it to be as wide as `D` - not anything in between.

I know I can do this using a `LayoutBuilder` and a hardcoded condition to check if the available width is at least `X` pixels. But is there a widget out there that does it without needing a hardcoded min-width? Just adapting to the actual width of `B`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stateful widget and use `addPostFrameCallback` to get the size from the context:

```dart
WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  if (context.size is Size) {
    print('My context size is: ${context.size}');
  }
});
```

If you want to know the sizes of both widgets, you can assign a global key to each, and then use a `RenderBox` to get their sizes.

Any solution that you go with to dynamically get the size of widgets will necessarily mean that they will get laid out, which may not be cheap, depending on the widgets themselves.

Comment: Thanks, but as it says in the question, that's exactly what I want to avoid doing.

Comment: Apologies. Updated the answer.